# How to select observations with specific values from a column in python

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have 2 columns, "a" and "b" now if column "a" has 500 observations with values 0 to 10. How would I create a separate data frame that just included all the observations where "a" = 1.

I want a separate data frame containing all observations where "a" = 1, but I don't want the new data frame to contain the b column.

I'm new to python and unsure about how to do this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just want to select the target column where the condition is met. You could use loc to specify the condition to match rows (`df["a"] == 1`) and columns (`"a"`):

```
df.loc[df["a"] == 1, "a"]
```